# Axios instance/function not receiving argument?

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I have a next.js App which has a working axios call, which I am trying to refactor. I have it mostly working, but I can't get my new function to receive arguments.

This problem has two components to it, my next.js page, and the external custom module where I am writing my functions to use axios to call the YouTube API to retrieve info.

My next.js getStaticProps call looks like this. I know this is working. Note the function where I am trying to pass in the video ID. (The 'const = video' line)

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  // It's important to default the slug so that it doesn't return "undefined"
  const { slug = "" } = context.params;
  const film = await client.fetch(query, { slug });

  const video = await youtube.grabVideoInfo(film.VideoID);

  return {
    props: {
      film,
      video,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}
```

I have tried writing the axios call in two ways, trying to pass in the video ID as an argument. Neither of which work, and fail to call from the API, stating an invalid video ID, which means it isn't being passed in.

The first way:

```
const grabVideoInfo = async (videoId) => {
  const videoGrab = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?",
    params: {
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
      part: "snippet",
      id: videoId,
      key: KEY,
    },
  });

  const query = await videoGrab.get().then(
    (response) => {
      return response.data.items[0];
    },
    (error) => {
      return error.toJSON();
    }
  );
  return query;
};
```

The second way:

```
const grabVideoInfo = async (videoId) => {
  const videoGrab = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?",
    params: {
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
      part: "snippet",
      key: KEY,
    },
  });

  const query = await videoGrab.get({ params: { id: videoId } }).then(
    (response) => {
      return response.data.items[0];
    },
    (error) => {
      return error.toJSON();
    }
  );
  return query;
};
```

And this is the fully working version that I am trying to rewrite, which is live on the app currently. This demonstrates that the getStaticProps client call is working.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  // It's important to default the slug so that it doesn't return "undefined"
  const { slug = "" } = context.params;
  const film = await client.fetch(query, { slug });

  const KEY = process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
  const conn = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/",
    params: {
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
      part: "snippet",
      id: film.videoID,
      key: KEY,
    },
  });

  const video = await (await conn.get("videos?")).data.items[0];

  return {
    props: {
      film,
      video,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm really scratching my head with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your refactor is accessing `film.VideoId` where the original uses `film.videoId`.

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU. I was seriously getting angry that it wasn't just working!!! It actually completely didn't make sense to me. 

I'm so relieved, I can't believe it was such a stupidly simple issue. I can't thank you enough!!